# How can I scale color bar and make it consistent with color of plot

Tags: plotting, legending

for a minimal example, I have these two sets of data

```
data = {Table[{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4, 0.1}], 
   Table[{x, y, 10 Sin[x y]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4, 0.1}]};
```

they are scaled 1/10  and I would like to plot them with different scaling like this

```
scaling = {1, 10};    
Table[ListDensityPlot[Flatten[data[[j]], 1], PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotRangePadding -> None, 
      ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0.7, 1], 
           RGBColor[0, 0.7, 1, 1], RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 0], 
           RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0, 1], RGBColor[0.6, 0, 0, 1]}, 
          Rescale[#, {-scaling[[j]], scaling[[j]]}]] &), 
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
      PlotLegends -> 
       BarLegend[{Automatic, {-scaling[[j]], scaling[[j]]}}]], {j, 1, 2}]
```

as you can see the color bar is not consisting of plot color. I tried to add `ColorFunctionScaling -> True` to the `BarLegend` but still did not work? how can I solve this stupid silly error of MMA? By the way, if I plot each case separately without using `Table` it is working fine?!!!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define color function as a function beforehand.

```
data = {Table[{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4, 0.1}], 
   Table[{x, y, 10 Sin[x y]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4, 0.1}]};
scaling = {1, 10};
cf[j_] := (Blend[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0.7, 1], RGBColor[0, 0.7, 1, 1], 
     RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0, 1], 
     RGBColor[0.6, 0, 0, 1]}, 
    Rescale[#, {-scaling[[j]], scaling[[j]]}]] &)

Table[ListDensityPlot[Flatten[data[[j]], 1], PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None
  , ColorFunction -> cf[j]
  , ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{Automatic, {-scaling[[j]], scaling[[j]]}}]], {j, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Put the color function option value inside `With[{j = j},...]` to make sure  that the value of `j` is injected inside `Function` construct:

```
Table[ListDensityPlot[Flatten[data[[j]], 1], PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> (With[{j = j}, 
     Blend[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0.7, 1], RGBColor[0, 0.7, 1, 1], 
        RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0, 1], 
        RGBColor[0.6, 0, 0, 1]}, 
       Rescale[#, {-scaling[[j]], scaling[[j]]}]] &] ), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{Automatic, {-scaling[[j]], scaling[[j]]}}]], {j, 1, 2}]
```

Alternatively, wrap  `ListDensityPlot[...]` with `With[{j = j},...]`:

```
Table[With[{j = j}, 
  ListDensityPlot[Flatten[data[[j]], 1], PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0.7, 1], 
        RGBColor[0, 0.7, 1, 1], RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 0], 
        RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0, 1], RGBColor[0.6, 0, 0, 1]}, 
       Rescale[#, {-scaling[[j]], scaling[[j]]}]] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic]],
 {j, 1, 2}]
```

both methods give

[image]

**Note:** `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {-scaling[[j]], scaling[[j]]}}]` gives the same result.

Comment: What does `With[{j=j},...]` do? It looks very strange to me

Comment: @Joe, `With[{j=j}, body]` inserts values of the iterator `j` inside held expressions inside _body_ . In this case, the rhs of the part of the body `ColorFunction -> (stuff &)`, being a `Function`, has  the attribute `HoldAll`  -- which means _stuff_  is maintained in _unevaluated_ form, hence, any `j` that appears inside _stuff_ stays unevaluated as `j` opposed to being replaced by the iterator value. For a simpler example, try `SetAttributes[FOO, HoldAll];` and compare `Table[FOO[i, j], {j, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]` vs
`Table[With[{i = i, j = j}, FOO[i, j]], {j, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]`.

Answer (score 4):

As you indicated, the plots are fine when done individually so use `Map` rather than `Table`

```
$Version

(* "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {Table[{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4, 0.1}], 
   Table[{x, y, 10 Sin[x y]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4, 0.1}]};

Row[
 ListDensityPlot[#,
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotRangePadding -> None,
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[{
         RGBColor[0, 0, 0.7, 1], RGBColor[0, 0.7, 1, 1],
         RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0, 1],
         RGBColor[0.6, 0, 0, 1]}, #] &),
    PlotLegends -> Automatic,
    ImageSize -> 250] & /@
  (Flatten[#, 1] & /@ data)]
```

[image]